# import mysql database into mariadb

Tags: mysql, database, import, mariadb

Tried importing a database backup(.sql) from docker container mysql:5.6 into my local MySQL(MariaDB).

Here is the commands I've used:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < /opt/database.sql  
mysql -u root -p  database=database_name </opt/database.sql
```

Also wanna try mysqlimport but I always encounter the same error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
>   Copy' at line 1

Can anyone please tell me what is the right syntax on importing database from mysql into mariadb.

Comment: Remove the first 4 lines from your `sql` file and try again

Comment: @Hackerman thank you for the response but still no luck bro.

Comment: Can you post the first 10 lines of you sql file?

Comment: @Ullas It's my first post here in stack overflow sorry for the wrong format. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hackerman Here it is bro:   
`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine   wrapper  
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.  
  
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its  
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective  
owners.  
  
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]  
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.  
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?`

darn bad format sorry!

Comment: You need to get rid of all the non sql text!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tried to create a dump with mysql command line client instead of mysqldump.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've used `mysql dump` instead of `mysqldump` command. @Georg

Comment: what is the full syntax to dump with mysql command instead of mysqldump ?